# Creating a database to show all users mousemovements real-time/ live that are currently on website

Tags: php, jquery, database, mouseevent, interactive

I've experimented with heatmap.js found here: http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/. This example shows one user's real-time mouse-movements.

I also have experimented with tracking clicks here: http://css-tricks.com/tracking-clicks-building-a-clickmap-with-php-and-jquery/. This example shows how to store several user's click within a database then display it with a click of a button.

I'd now like to create a "live" version of mouse-movements like example 1 I've provided but create a database like example 2 that everyone can view all the mouse-movements at once... I suppose I'm trying to create a "live" space where each user is a mouse cursor and they can see other persons/mouse cursors' movements/heat.

I know this is not a very "specific" question. And that I have nothing to show for development. But I would really appreciate it if anyone knows of examples, demos etc... I can look at and learn from. Thanks ahead of time. You Rule!

Answer (score 0):

Thats a lot of data to store ;)

For displaying movements try REDIS

It will be much more faster, then normar DB - but You can store only key:value pairs - but this should be enough for You:

```
user_id:pos_x,pos_y;pos_x1,pos_y1; etc
```

Warning :D I don't know the limit for value length!

Also there is a mongo DB that's a no-relational DB but can do fast operations on huge amount of data. Consider it as well! :)